# COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY...) - the result of this window function is counterintuitive

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions

So I've been melting my brain for the whole evening and still haven't come up with a sophisticated answer. I hope you can help!

So I have this table, made of unique IDs and registration time (200 inquiries):

| USER ID | REGISTRATION_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-01-01' |
| 2 | '2020-01-01' |
| 3 | '2019-01-01' |
| 4 | '2018-01-01' |

**...down to 200 IDs**

This window function call

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) OVER(ORDER BY registration_time desc) as cnt, registration_time 
FROM user;
```

...returns the following (the middle attribute goes down to 200 rows):

| USER ID | REGISTRATION_TIME | REGISTRATION_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2021-01-01' |
| 2 | 2 | '2020-01-01' |
| 3 | 3 | '2019-01-01' |
| 4 | 5 | '2018-01-01' |
| 5 | 5 | '2018-01-01' |
| 6 | 6 | '2017-01-01' |

---

So, I see that `COUNT(*)` numbers every row (descending, according to registration_time, as per instruction) and increments it by 1 for each recurring inquiry.

How is that? What I know about `COUNT`, is that it calculates the number of rows in a given table. What I know about window functions - particularly the one without `PARTITION BY` - is that they gather all rows in one group.

What `COUNT(*)` does here, really resembles of what `SUM(1) OVER(ORDER BY ... rows unbounded preceding)` does (correct me if I'm wrong)

So, what I expect, is 1 for every row... But instead, I see an arithmetic sequence...

I wonder how exactly does it work? Thank you very much in advance!

P.S.. I tried Googling but didn't find something relevant...

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(1)` are always equivalent.

Comment: Alright, I've edited.

Comment: Presumably, you can try to find this in the documentation, mySQL defaults to "ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING" when you give an order by in a count(). Why you would be giving an order by in a count() here is a different story.

Comment: What I would expect is that I get the full table count back in ever row (not `1`), but both of our assumptions are incorrect as it turns out.

Comment: PS - sorry for the spam of edits. The markdown was showing up well in preview but it took some trial and error to get it looking right after saving.

Comment: @JNevill I was expecting a full table count back as well. Tbh, I put that into my post first, but then on second thought, I edited it. For some reason...

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. You're creating sliding windows. For each row, the sliding window consists of current row and all previous rows. The previous is determined by order by clause. If the values have ties then exact behavior depends on rows vs range specification. That explains incrementing counts.

Comment: @SalmanA thank you so much! That is what I was thinking of from the beginning of when I first got into this topic today, and the confirmation is what I needed!

Comment: See also https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-rows-range-window-functions/ and https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/ and https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-2-the-frame/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL 8.0 Window Function Frame Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html)

> In the absence of a frame clause *[stackoverflow edit: The "frame clause" being the `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` that you noted]*, the default frame depends on
> whether an ORDER BY clause is present:
>
> With ORDER BY: The default frame includes rows from the partition start through the current row, including all peers of the current row
> (rows equal to the current row according to the ORDER BY clause). The
> default is equivalent to this frame specification:
>
> ```
> RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
> ```

Which describes the results you are seeing

Comment: Alright, but how does it explain this strange (for me) behavior of COUNT(*). COUNT(1) or COUNT(\*) - they're the same right? Afaik simply takes 1 for each row it goes through, where is anything about accumulation?

Comment: I didn't see any mention of `count(1)` in your questions. Perhaps I am overlooking? `Sum(1)` however, I would expect this same default frame behavior, based on this documentation. Now I'm curious what `COUNT(1)` would do. That's an odd thing to run though.

Comment: Yeah, I can see why sum(1) would work, it, well, sums things... But COUNT counts rows no? My brain just can't grasp the concept...

If you see my inquiry more closely you'll notice the window function I am calling to get the results.

Comment: It is counting the rows, just over a window (subset) defined by the range. "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" says: ordering by registration_time, count how many rows come before the current row's value.

Comment: The thing is `COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY <something>)` if it worked in a literal sense, it would count the number of rows in the partition and return that number for every row. But it has this nice default behavior of assuming you meant `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` which, if you ran that frame definition in any RDBMS would give you the exact same results that you are seeing. Well... many RDBMSs, I think some of them don't allow a `count(*)` in a window function.

Comment: @Error_2646 please correct me if I'm wrong: when it comes to the window function COUNT, it generates a bucket -> puts 1st row in it -> counts the amount (current and preceding) -> puts 2nd row -> counts the total amount (which is current and unbound preceding) -> and goes just like this to the very end? For me to get this, I need a precise comprehension of the concept

Comment: @MordecaiOD If that explanation makes sense to you and lines up with what you are seeing, you can think about it like that. Fact is the implementation, what mysql actually does is going to be sorcery based on what the optimizer thinks is the most efficient plan. Maybe a bad analogy, but you can think of it like a 1000 step journey. If you are on the 563rd step. count(*) over () is 1000, the total number regardless of position. count(*) over ( order by individual_step ) is 563 - the count of steps up to your current point.

Comment: @MordecaiOD It might get confusing if you are trying to think about orderings as buckets. Partitions map to a bucket metaphor much more intuitively.

Comment: @MordecaiOD What's not made clear here is the `ROWS` vs `RANGE` distinction, and the counter-intuitive fact that the default is `RANGE` when nearly everyone would expect `ROWS`. `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` and `SUM(1)` will all give the same results, the question is what the frame actually is.